# closest('tr') value is undefined when getting id from table

Tags: jquery, laravel

Trying to get the ID from table when button clicked, but alert box showing "undefined"

```
<table id="buffalosummery" class="table table-bordered table-hover table" style="width:100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Breed Type</th>
         <th>Gender</th>
         <th>Purchase Date</th>
         <th>Purchase Price</th>
         <th>Pregnant</th>
         <th>Avg Milk / Day</th>
         <th>Health Status</th>
         <th>Animal Status</th>
         <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
   <tbody>
      @foreach ($buffalodata as $item )
      <tr>
         <input type="hidden" class="deletebuffaloid" value="{{$item->buffaloID}}">
         <td>{{$item->buffaloID}}</td>
         <td>{{$item->breedtype}}</td>
         <td>{{$item->gendertype}}</td>
         <td>{{ date('d-m-Y', strtotime ($item->purchasedate)) }}</td>
         <td>{{$item->purchaseprice}}</td>
         <td>{{$item->pregnant}}</td>
         <td>{{$item->avgmilk}}</td>
         <td>{{$item->health}}</td>
         <td>{{$item->status}}</td>
         <td>
            <a href="{{ route('viewBuffalobyid', ['buffaloid' => $item->buffaloID]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">View</a> 
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger deletedatabtn"><i class="fas fa-trash" title="Delete"></i></button>
         </td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
   </tbody>
   </thead>
</table>
```

Delete button Event

```
$('.deletedatabtn').on('click', function () { 
    var delete_buffaloid = $(this).closest('tr').find('.deletebuffaloid').val();
    alert(delete_buffaloid);
}
```

Did i miss, something..... Thanks

Comment: The code you've shown in the question works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/1bujmd78/. Check you've setup your page correctly with the relevant script references, and in the right order, along with a document.ready handler. Also check the console for errors.

Comment: Just before your `$('.deletedatabtn').on` add `console.log($('.deletedatabtn').length)` and check in the console (F12) for the result.  If it's `0` then your js code is running too soon; before the buttons have been generated.   Wrap it in doc.ready *may* do the trick depending on how you get your table.

Comment: Alternatively: change `$('.deletedatabtn').on('click', function () {` to `$(document).on("click", function () {`

Comment: Hmmm, if you're getting an alert, then that's not the issue.  Comments left for reference.

Comment: Thanks for Quick reply.... in console.log showing number but not 0.... and Yes Alert box is coming but showing "Undefined"

Comment: Yes.. in jsfiddle its working fine.... I change the code .. 
Added "data-id" in button with required id and then 
var delete_buffaloid = $(this).data('id');
now alert is coming for each id...
Thanks all for your support...